# Input loses focus when using custom input for Formik Field in FieldArray

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I am using custom input components to handle my form data, and noticed strange behaviour. Only when I am using `FieldArray` with custom input components the input loses focus as I type.

Here is the form setup:

```
<Formik
  enableReinitialize
  initialValues={{ ...getInitialState() }}
  onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
    save(values, actions)
  }}
  validationSchema={schema}
  >
  {({ values, isSubmitting, setFieldValue, dirty }) => (
    ...
    <Images />
    ...
  )}
</Formik>
```

And inside my `Images` component

```
import { imageState } from "states"
import Input from "form/input"

function Images() {
  ...
  return (
    <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <FieldArray
          name="images.posters"
          render={({ form, push, remove }) => {
          const images = form.values.images.poster
          return (
            <>
              <button onClick={() => push(imageState)}>Add Poster</button>
              {images.map((image, index) => (
                <div key={index} className={styles.imageGroup}>
                  <Field //using custom input loses focus
                    name={`images.poster.${index}.src`}
                    component={Input} 
                  />
                 <Field //using Formik default component doesn't loose focus
                    name={`images.poster.${index}.src`}
                  />
                 <button onClick={() => remove(index)}>Remove Poster</button>
                </div>
              ))}
            </>
          )}}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is there another way I have to use custom inputs for FieldArray? I do not experience this problem when I am not using FieldArray.